# Nested Loops Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: python, nested-loops

I am trying to write a program which will ask the user to enter a number. I then need to validate it is in the fib sequence

**Code:**

```
# asking the user to input number
number = int(input("Enter a number: "))

# creating empty list to be filled
sequence = [0, 1]

x = -2
y = -1


# append items to list
for i in range(number):
    x+=2
    y+=2
# this code will be executed 'length' times
    sequence.append(x+y)

# This should be somewhere in the loop: 
if number in sequence:
    print("The number is in the Fibonacci sequence")
else:
    print("The number is not in the Fibonacci sequence")
```

**Expected Output:**

Fibonacci Sequence = 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, ….

```
Enter a number: 5
>>> The number is in the Fibonacci sequence
```

Comment: Your `number` variable is a string. Convert it to an integer. And then don't do `len(number)`.

Comment: And you don't know upfront how many fibonacci numbers you need, so you should go until you reach the number you are looking for.

Comment: Last thing: there are no nested loops in your code - why did you put them in the question title?

Comment: zvone because I don't see how it can be done that way

Comment: I suggest you break this into smaller pieces. First write a program that prints out the first 20 numbers in the fibonacci sequence. Then modify the program to let the user input a number `n` and print out the first `n` numbers in the sequence. Finally modify this program to  solve the problem completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do some iteration (or recursion) in order to find the sequence of Fibonacci numbers. Here is one way to do it with a while loop:

```
number = int(input("Enter a number: "))

sequence = [0, 1]

i= 0
while True:
    new_item = sequence[i] + sequence[i+1]
    if new_item == number or number in [0,1]:
        print("The number is in the Fibonacci sequence")
        break
    elif new_item > number:
        print("The number is not in the Fibonacci sequence")
        break
    sequence.append(new_item)
    i+=1
```

Notice that you will iterate until the new item in your Fibonacci sequence is greater than or equal to the number the user input.

Comment: @coder80 since 0 and 1 are initial values put a check for them before the loop...

Comment: I have provided a check to see if `number in [0,1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Sequence doesn't have a position x or y. The line where you append to the sequence should read `sequence.append(x+y)`

Comment: It still doesn't work. Even if the number is in the sequence, it says "The number is not in the Fibonacci sequence"

Comment: Oh, you also should change `for i in range(len(number)):` to `for i in range(int(number)):` If that doesn't work consider `for i in range(int(number)+1):` as python won't execute the for loop with the stop value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm thinking about this too simply but according to your question, it sounds like a Fibonacci sequence is provided to you. If that is the case you can just use `in`, i.e.

```
x = 5 # this will be user's input
fib = [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34]
if x in fib:
    print('Number is in sequence')
else:
    print('Number is not in sequence')
```

If you have to generate your own Fibonacci sequence then you may want to consider using recursion.

Comment: I added what I expect it to output

Comment: The sequence could go on forever so I don't think we can create our own list

Comment: since the purpose of this list is to check for what is inside it and not for it to be displayed as a sequence i think a set would be better since it uses hashes so it becomes a O(1) solution once you have the list/set

Answer (score 0):

alternativly you could just calculate the fibonachi numebers

```
def fibo(n):
    p = (1+5**.5)/2
    q = (1-5**.5)/2
    return int(1/5**.5*(p**n-q**n))

def fiba(num):
     count = 0
     while fibo(count) <= num:
             if fibo(count) == num:
                     return "YES!"
             count += 1
     return "NO!"
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to factor out the `fibonacci` into a generator and then iterator over that generator until `>= number`, e.g.:

```
def fib():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a+b

In []    
number = 5 # int(input("Enter a number: "))

for f in fib():
    if f >= number:
        break

if number == f:
    print("The number is in the Fibonacci sequence")
else:
    print("The number is not in the Fibonacci sequence")

Out[]:
The number is in the Fibonacci sequence
```

You could use `itertools.takewhile` to replace the for loop, e.g.:

```
import itertools as it
from collections import deque

f = deque(it.takewhile(lambda n: n <= number, fib()), maxlen=1).pop()

...
```